# How do we check for value of a dataframe column is not null?

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I would like to read a value of a column from a dataframe and check if that value is not null and the length of the value is <= 500

**My code :**

```
 import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

object OmegaProcess
 {
    // Some scala lines of Code 

 ....
 val line_flag =   generateomegaLineFlag(omegaDF)

 def generateomegaLineFlag(omegaDF: DataFrame): Int = {

     if (omegaDF("omega_file_name") != null && length(omegaDF("omega_file_name")) <= 500 )
        {
           //Some Lines of code .....

         }
100
  }

}
```

But it does not compile due this below error

```
  Type mismatch expected :Boolean, actual: Column
```

Could some one help me to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using isNotNull for checking aganist Null values

```
if (omegaDF("omega_file_name").isNotNull && length(omegaDF("omega_file_name")) <= 500 )
```